# Passing in a query string to generate a new URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a web page with a dropdown list and when you select a product the page refreshes with the new information. What I want to do is pass into the page a query string so I am able to open up the pages via a URL instead of clicking on a dropdown list item.

I am not sure how to do this in the page load. My page defaults to the default option but I would like the other dropdown list item to be able to be accessed via a URL so I need to know how to pass it a query string.

```
 private void BindDropDownList()
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] productTexts;

                    string[] productValues;





                    BizManager biz = new BizManager();

                    biz.GetProductSeriesList(out productTexts, out productValues);

                    DDLProduct.Items.Clear();

                    int x = 0;
                    foreach (string s in productTexts)
                    {
                        ListItem li = new ListItem(s, productValues[x]);
                        x++;
                        DDLProduct.Items.Add((li));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrMsg = App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

here I am calling the params from a key in the web config, but I need my URL to look like this

https://apps.co.uk/PackingStatsShiftOverview/Default.aspx?Product=G120C

or

https://apps.co.uk/PackingStatsShiftOverview/Default.aspx?Product=PM240-2

or

https://apps.co.uk/PackingStatsShiftOverview

You access the query string value with

Request.QueryString[“Product”]

You need to handle it not existing & do what it does now, Otherwise, your dropdown needs to default to the QueryString value.

Comment: Show code of the dropdown list and its logic.

Comment: It's not the best to go around doing `catch (Exception ex)` - it's an anti-pattern. You should really only ever catch a **specific** exception that you can **meaningfully** handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Check if the QueryString exists and if so check the DropDownList values for a matching value. When found set the correct DropDownList value.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Product"] != null)
{
    string product = Request.QueryString["Product"].ToString();

    if (DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(x => x.Value == product))
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do the `.ToList()` here?

Comment: @Enigmativity. No reason. I quickly wrote that without realizing that `.Items` is already a collection.